# RegExp Escape Problem?

Tags: regex, flex3

I need some RegExp help for a Flex 3 website. I'm trying to find this:

```
px;'</img>
```

And replace it with:

```
px;'></img>
```

I've tried:

```
var tester: String = " blah height: 0px;'<\img>blah";                           

var pattern1:RegExp = /px;'<\/img>/g;
tester = tester.replace(pattern1, "px;'></img>");
```

I think that the problem is with escaping the / in the img tag, but I'm not sure.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex looks right. Your test string, on other hand, has a backslash instead of a forward slash:

```
var tester: String = " blah height: 0px;'<\img>blah";
```

Comment: John, thanks so much for the message. I missed the mistyped slash and thought that I had a problem with the escape.

Answer (score 2):

No need for regexp:

```
tester = tester.replace("px;'</img>", "px;'></img>");
```

As a rule of thumb, don't use regex unless what you are looking for is variable.

Comment: Hi quantumSoup, thank you for the post. Unfortunately, in this case, I have to use the dreaded RegExp as I have a few places where it needs to be changed. Thanks